# How to set the null value for a property of @NodeEntity?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I can't set any property to null via a Repository. 
For example, suppose I have the following entity:

```
@NodeEntity
class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

If this entity already exists in the db with `name:"Victor"`, then if I will save it like this:

```
User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
```

The `savedUser` will have `null` as name. But in the db the `name` property will be `Victor`.

**Any thoughts, why so? And how to set a property to the `null` value?**

---

PS: Seems like the key point, why `null`'s aren't set, may be found in the `EntityGraphMapper`:

```
for (PropertyReader propertyReader : entityAccessStrategy.getPropertyReaders(classInfo)) {
    Object value = propertyReader.read(entity);
    if (value != null) {
        nodeBuilder.addProperty(propertyReader.propertyName(), value);
    }
}
```

Such properties simply aren't taken into account... What should developers do?

Comment: Which version are you using? See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/examples/cineasts/annotated/CineastsIntegrationTest.java#L259 which passes. Are you doing something different?

Comment: I use SDN4.1.0M1. It leads to usage of OGM 2.0.0-M02. I do the same, but via Repository.

Comment: Can you try OGM 2.0.1? <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Great thanks, that you helped me to find the right way! Eventually I updated the version of SDN4 from 4.1.0.M1 to 4.1.1.RELEASE. Now all works fine.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to add this as an answer for anyone with the same problem, please accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your OGM version to 2.0.1 or your SDN version to 4.1.1.RELEASE.

For reference, there's a test that sets properties to null: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/2.0/core/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/examples/cineasts/annotated/CineastsIntegrationTest.java#L259